# $_FILES operations execute even though IF statement is false

Tags: php, file

I am trying to add a file upload ability to an internal company ticketing system.  The code works fine for the actual upload.  The problem I am running into is that if there is no file, the code still executes.  I have tried many things, from using the $_FILES error coding to adding a select menu to choose if you want to add a file or not, but the code still runs.

It works like this:

1. Ticket info is processed and entered into DB = dates, ticket info, email strings, etc
2. File should then be validated and uploaded, and moved to a new folder (named the ticket number)
3. File name and directory path are added to the DB.
4. All info is passed to the notification email which is then sent out.

When this script runs, if there is no file, the DB entry is made, and the info is added to the email, but it links to non-existant directory.

Interesting tidbit: The code to make the new directory does NOT execute without the file, this is the correct action.  Confusing thing is it's in the same block of code.

I have spent a day and half trying to figure this out without resolution.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//fileUpload
$fixedFileName = "";
$fileProcessed = 0;

if($_POST['yesFile'] == "yes") { //select option in form - 
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "txt", "pdf", "zip", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "pcf");
    $varForExt = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($varForExt);

    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            //echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            $fixedFileName = print_r($_FILES);
        } else {
            $fixedFileName = trim(str_replace(' ','_', $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

            $dirToMake = '/var/www/html/eis/uploads/ESIG/';
            $dirToMake .= $_SESSION['lastRID'].'/';
            mkdir($dirToMake);

            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dirToMake.$fixedFileName)) {
                //insert filepath/file into sql
                $fileProcessed = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged around your conditionals to verify the values they are evaluating are the values you expect?

Comment: There is no way a if statement will execute if the condition is false. The your condition is somehow returning true while you expect false... just check the variables in your conditions to see which one isn't as expected...

Comment: I have tried a few different code checkers/validaters, and visually matched all of my {} a few times.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) hole in your code. Enjoy having your server pwn3d. You're also allowing malicious users to scribble files on your server pretty much anywhere they want. You should NOT be following the w3fool "example" for uploads. Their code is worse than crap.

Comment: Agreed agreed - lucky thing is only employees use it, and behind a few layers of firewall.  it's not accessable at all from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "on");`

I suspect the files array is empty, and php is seeing the undefined `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` as 0 which passes your test.

try adding `isset($_FILES["file"])` to your first test

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000 && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
```

Comment: This seems to work, though I was sure I had tried it.  Thanks to everyone for the input.